# Formal System and Formal Logical System

Tags: logic, formal-systems

I was reading the Wikipedia article for [Mathematical_logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system#Logical_system). When reaching [Formal_logical_systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system), I was curious about its definition and clicked into its own article [Logical_system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system#Logical_system), which redirected me to the article for [Formal_system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system), where I found [the definition for formal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system):

> In formal logic, a formal system (also
>   called a logical calculus[citation
>   needed]) consists of a formal language
>   and a set of inference rules, used to
>   derive (to conclude) an expression
>   from one or more other premises that
>   are antecedently supposed (axioms) or
>   derived (theorems). The axioms and
>   rules may be called a deductive
>   apparatus. A formal system may be
>   formulated and studied for its
>   intrinsic properties, or it may be
>   intended as a description (i.e. a
>   model) of external phenomena.

and [the definition for logical system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system#Logical_system)

> A logical system or, for short, logic,
>   is a formal system together with a
>   form of semantics, usually in the form
>   of model-theoretic interpretation,
>   which assigns truth values to
>   sentences of the formal language, that
>   is, formulae that contain no free
>   variables. A logic is sound if all
>   sentences that can be derived are true
>   in the interpretation, and complete
>   if, conversely, all true sentences can
>   be derived.

I thought logical system and formal system were the same concept by self-learning, but here it says logical system is a formal system plus semantics/interpretation. Isn't that in logical system we don't care about the semantics/meaning of propositions and that's the reason that the subject is called formal logic? But why here it says logical system has semantics/interpretation? How to understand "semantics" and whether logical system and formal system are the same?

Is logical system a special example of formal system, in the same sense as Lambda calculus is a special example of formal system as in [examples of formal systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system#See_also)? Or is logical system a formal system with additional structure called "semantics", in the same sense as topological vector space is a vector space with additional topological structure?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We definitely care that formal logic has a formal semantics. Here's a [list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/why-do-we-need-formal-semantics-for-predicate-logic) of reasons why. More simply, we need to know very precisely what a formalism means. Without this precise definition, there's a lot of wasted time arguing about what things mean.

To answer your other questions, consider the simplest, most accessible case: propositional logic. We have atomic propositions, represented by simple symbols like P and Q, and then formulas built up from the usual connectives like and ($\wedge$), or ($\vee$), and not ($\neg$). Together with the proof theory which governs how we do deductions, we now have a formal system by your definition.

The [semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth) is built by introducing a separate meta-level, totally outside everything in the previous paragraph. In that level we define two truth values, true and false. In this level we also define a function which maps each propositional symbol to a truth value. Let's call this function I. Here's one possible version of I: {(P,true),(Q,false)}. I is the interpretation function. Finally, we define the usual semantics of the connectives: for example, and ($\wedge$) means both its arguments must be true.

Voila! We have now sketchily defined the semantics of propositional logic. If it sounds like truth tables, it is: each row of a truth table corresponds to one possible interpretation function. Here's a [nice writeup](http://logic.stanford.edu/classes/cs157/2009/lectures/lecture02.pdf).

The nice thing is that all modern formal semantic theories look like the propositional case, just higher-powered: they all have a separate meta-level to define the semantics and an interpretation function to map from the object layer of formulas to the meta-level containing the semantics (roughly speaking).

So now we can quickly answer your questions: a logical system has "semantics/interpretation" because we need to define a separate meta-level and an interpretation function to let us interpret the meanings of well-formed formulas.
A formal system and a logical system are not the same because we can define a formal system that has no formal semantics, say, a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) or a well-defined card game. Finally, there is additional structure to define the semantics of a logical system, but on a totally separate meta-level.