# Are Real Numbers a Formal System?

Tags: real-numbers, axioms, meta-math, formal-systems

I don't know a lot of mathematics but I have noticed that every branch of Mathematics has the same structure: some axioms (For example in Geometry might be ***Euclid's Axioms***, in Probability might be ***Kolmogorov Axioms***), and some theorems that are originated from them. So, as the way I understand it, mathematics is laid out in something called a "***Formal System***". I also have heard that this concept has created a lot of debate starting from 1921 when David Hilbert proposed to use it as the foundation for the knowledge in mathematics. Then Kurt Godel came and the rest is famous history that I don't understand. But before trying to grasp at: What are "Godel's Incompleteness Theorems"?, I would like to understand first of all, what is a ***Formal System***?

Formal systems have these things:

> ***1) A Language***
>
> ***2) A Logical Formal System***
>
> ***3) Indefinite Terms***
>
> ***4) Definitions***
>
> ***5) Propositions (Axioms)***
>
> ***6) Propositions (Theorems)***

For example, in the case of ***Real Numbers*** $ \mathbb{R}  $ we have:

> ***1) A Language***
>
> ...
>
> ***2) A Logical Formal System***
>
> ...
>
> ***3) Indefinite Terms***
>
> ...
>
> ***4) Definitions***
>
> ...
>
> ***5) Axioms***
>
> There are three axioms:
>
> - ***Field Axioms***
>
>   ***F1***: If $ a, b \in \mathbb{R} $, so $ a + b $, $ ab \in \mathbb{R} $  ... (Closeness Axioms)
>
>   ***F2***: If $ a, b \in \mathbb{R} $, so $ a + b = b + a $ and $ ab = ba $ ... (Commutativity Axioms)
>
>   ***F3***: If $ a, b, c \in \mathbb{R} $, so $ a + (b+c) = (a+b) + c $ and $ a(bc) = (ab)c $  ... (Associativity Axioms)
>
>   ***F4***: If $ a, b, c \in \mathbb{R} $, so $ a(b+c) = ab +ac $ ... (Distributivity Axiom)
>
>   ***F5***: There are $0,1 \in \mathbb{R} $, with $ 0 \neq 1 $, so that if $ a \in \mathbb{R}$, so $ a +0 =a $ and $ (a)(1) = a   $ ...
>     (Identities Axioms)
>
>   ***F6***: If $ a \in \mathbb{R} $, there is $ a_1 \in \mathbb{R}   $, so that $ a + a_1 = 0   $, and if a $ a \in \mathbb{R}   $ with  $ a \neq 0  $,  so there is $ a_2 \in \mathbb{R}   $ so that $ (a)(a_2) =1 $ ... (Inverses Axioms)
> - ***Order Axioms***
>
>   ***O1***: If $ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, then, only and just only of the next propositions is true:
>
>   i) $ a= b  $
>
>   ii) $ a<b $
>
>   iii) $ b<a  $ ... (Trichotomy Axiom)
>
>   ***O2***: If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ a<b  $, $b<c$, so $ a<c$ ... (Transitivity Axiom)
>
>   ***O3***: If $ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, c> 0    $ and $ a<b  $, so $ ab < bc  $ ... (Product Consistency)
>
>   ***O4***: if $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}    $ and $ a<b  $, so $ a+c <b+c   $ ... (Addition Consistency)
> - ***Completeness Axiom***
>
>   ***C1***: If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}   $, so that:
>
>   1) $ a \neq \emptyset   $
>
>   2) $ A  $ is bounded from above
>
> so, $ A  $ has a supremum in $ \mathbb{R}  $
>
> ***6) Theorems***
>
> There are many theorems, for example, "***The Addition of Fractions***":
>
> $ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}  =  \frac{ad+bc}{bd}  $
>
> and the proof is:
>
> $  \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = ab^{-1} + cd^{-1} $ (Definition)
>
> $ = (ab^{-1})1 + (cd^{-1})1    $  (F5)
>
> $ = (ab^{-1})(dd^{-1}) + (cd^{-1})(b b^{-1})    $ (F6)
>
> $ = a (b^{-1} d d^{-1} ) + c(d^{-1}bb^{-1})  $ (F3)
>
> $ = a (db^{-1} d^{-1}) + c(bd^{-1}b^{-1})   $ (F2)
>
> $  = (ad) (b^{-1} d^{-1}) + (cb) ( b^{-1} d^{-1}  ) $ (F3)
>
> $  = (ad) (b^{-1} d^{-1}) + (bc)(b^{-1} d^{-1})    $ (F2)
>
> $  = (ad+bc)(b^{-1} d^{-1})   $ (F4)
>
> $  = (ad + bc)(bd)^{-1}     $ (it can be proved with help of another
>   theorem)
>
> $  = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}    $ ... QED

I don't understand very well, in the case of Real Numbers, what are: "***The Language***", "***The Logical Formal System***", "***The Indefinite Terms***" and "***The Definitions***"?, are they really a "Formal System"? an special case of a Formal system called: An Axiomatic System? What is really a Formal System? Who was the first one that created these axioms for Real Numbers? if formal systems are not the foundation knowledge for mathematics, then, what do we continue learning Axioms of Real Numbers this way? What would be the real foundation of Real Numbers?

Comment: See the post [Formal system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16917/formal-system-and-formal-logical-system) as well as [Axiom Systems and Formal Systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408131/axiom-systems-and-formal-systems)

Comment: Regarding the title: NO, real numbers are... numbers. We describe them with a mathematical theory: call it the [*Theory of Real Numbers*](https://books.google.it/books?id=DvIJBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). We can axiomatize it and formalize it: if so, what we have is the formal theory of real numbers.

Comment: "Who was the first one ?" If not "the" first, for sure the most important: [Richard Dedekind](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dedekind-foundations/#FouAna).

Comment: See e.g. [Tarski's axiomatization of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axiomatization_of_the_reals)

Comment: Yes, I have also heard about Tarski's axiomatization, but that let's me more confused

Comment: So, the Formal Theory of Real Numbers, is a Formal System?